# push data to line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linechart

> trying to push data to line chart, but cannot see any line. what is
>   wrong here?

data look like this

```
[{"ev_id":null,"id":0,"name":"car","dwell_time":null,"no_visitor":3,"total_visitor":0,"timestamp":"/Date(1500699656000)/"},{"ev_id":null,"id":0,"name":"car","dwell_time":null,"no_visitor":2,"total_visitor":0,"timestamp":"/Date(1500526919000)/"},{"ev_id":null,"id":0,"name":"car","dwell_time":null,"no_visitor":6,"total_visitor":0,"timestamp":"/Date(1500526966000)/"},{"ev_id":null,"id":0,"name":"car","dwell_time":null,"no_visitor":1,"total_visitor":0,"timestamp":"/Date(1500527026000)/"}],[{"ev_id":null,"id":0,"name":"football","dwell_time":null,"no_visitor":11,"total_visitor":0,"timestamp":"/Date(1500534046000)/"},{"ev_id":null,"id":0,"name":"football","dwell_time":null,"no_visitor":1,"total_visitor":0,"timestamp":"/Date(1500526906000)/"},{"ev_id":null,"id":0,"name":"football","dwell_time":null,"no_visitor":4,"total_visitor":0,"timestamp":"/Date(1500526966000)/"},{"ev_id":null,"id":0,"name":"football","dwell_time":null,"no_visitor":10,"total_visitor":0,"timestamp":"/Date(1500530626000)/"}]]
```

20170807235208:446 [["car","#058DC7",[3,2,6,1]],["football","#50B432",[11,1,4,10]]]

and here is line chart code

```
  function temp(data) {

    var my_data = [];
    var colors = ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']

    $.each(data, function (i, value) {
        var key = "";
        var temp = [];
        var color = colors[i];
        $.each(value, function (index, values) {
            temp.push(values.no_visitor);
            key = values.name;
        })

        my_data.push([key, color, temp])

    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(my_data));
   // log data sample is mentioned in question details above

      var chart =   new Highcharts.chart('container1', {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'my chart'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'visitors'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: my_data
            });
    }
```

Please explain the issue in order to avoid it next time 
Note: this is using HighCharts

chart needs to look like this 
[image]

Comment: completely misunderstood . Can you add what  your `my_data` will be. How you are getting `values.no_visitor` and `values.name` inside $.each(...)??. Add Raw data from server here

Comment: my_data will be like `[["car","#058DC7",[3,2,6,1]],["football","#50B432",[11,1,4,10]],["movie","#ED561B",[11,1,4,10,3,2,6,1]]]`

Comment: question is updated. Please check the data object that I included in main question

Comment: I have updated the question, the image shows is how the chart should look like

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1faLz9fg/ check this. Is it ok

Comment: yeah, almost like that,but tool-tips number is not correct

Comment: yeah, done.. I just change arrays into object and bind objects into array.. Thanks

Comment: you graph also has time do you want that

Comment: I have changed your parsing code and prepared an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fsht9o4b/.

Comment: yeah. I would like to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Still some problem with your server data. Better get you data from server on ascending time interval.

For forming `series` data

```
$.each(data, function(i, value) {
  var key = "";
  var temp = [];
  var color = colors[i];
  $.each(value, function(index, values) {
    temp.push({
      x: Number(values.timestamp),
      y: values.no_visitor
    });
    key = values.name;
  })
  /*sorting based on time ascending*/
  temp = temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.x) - (b.x)
  });
  my_data.push({
    name: key,
    color: color,
    data: temp
  })

});
```

For showing date in xAxis:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
      month: '%e. %b',
    }

  }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjmqpjfd/) based on your data